# Get Sections of a Document to Match HTML Template

Tags: javascript, c#, html, pdf, docx

I want let the user import their `.docx` files and match the sections of `.docx` file with my `HTML` page template.

For example;

-Title of imported `.docx` file should be placed to template's title section,

-Contents of imported `.docx` file should be placed to template's content section,

-References of imported `.docx` file should be placed to template's reference section,

-Images of imported `.docx` file should be placed to template's image section,

and so on.

I have tried `mammoth` module but It only generates `HTML` and I cannot find separate sections.

I also think that I can convert the `.docx` file to `.pdf` and I used `libreoffice-convert` module to get `.pdf`.

Same problem, cannot get sections from the .pdf.

Is there any library in `JavaScript` or `.Net` to get sections of `.docx` or `.pdf` file?

Answer (score -2):

officegen on npm is good for that :)
Its support docx and pptx :)

Try to check this on npm ^^

Comment: Thanks for answer. officegen only generates .docx but cannot find sections of the document I think.